# Yii 1.1.15 - Unable to resolve the request "gii".

Tags: php, yii, gii

Добрый день!

Не судите строго, начинаю изучение Yii. Возникла ошибка: "Unable to resolve the request gii".
Работаю по документации http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/quickstart.first-app

Вот конфигурация:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'pwd',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        //'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        'generatorPaths'=>array(
            'common.gii',   // псевдоним пути
        ),
    ),
),
```

Подскажите, где ошибка?

Спасибо!

**UPD** Может ли быть проблема в том, что файлы фреймворка Yii расположены в другой директории и с правами другого пользователя? Но в этом случае не совсем понятно, почему не возникает ошибки прав доступа.

**UPD** Маршруты:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'gii'=>'gii',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

**UPD** Лог:

```
2014/11/16 12:59:25 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "gii".' in /custom_libs/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /custom_libs/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('gii')
#1 /custom_libs/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 /var/www/oriuger/data/www/site.ru/app/index.php(13): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/app/index.php?r=gii
---
```

Comment: Flur, gii -> gii - хотел добиться пути app/index.php/gii/ . Без маршрутов и с маршрутами ошибка выходит одна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, работает. Видимо, был кэш. Сейчас включил маршруты, без изменений. И поменялись url'ы для логина и т.д. (до этого внутренние ссылки не менялись при изменении маршрутов). Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Думаю yii не понял эту строчку ---->"'gii'=>'gii',", что вы вообще хотели добиться этой строчкой? А ошибку без маршрутов можно увидеть?

Answer (score 1):

Уберите параметр 'generatorPaths', может, поможет.

**Обновление**

А маршруты в 'urlManager' у вас правильно прописаны?

Comment: MasterAlex, убрал, но ошибка всё та же.

Comment: Пробовал без маршрутов и с маршрутами (добавил конфиг), запросы URL: http://wp2.original-portal.ru/app/index.php/gii/ и http://wp2.original-portal.ru/app/index.php?r=gii . По первому URL выдаётся просто главная страница, второй отдаёт ошибку.